# Import psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am stuck trying to import psycopg2. I am working in MacOSX10.10.1 and have downloaded the one-click version of Postgresql (http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload). When I try to import psycopg2 I get this error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Reason: image not found
```

I have already try this:

```
rm /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib 
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

For each of libssl.1.0.0.dylib, libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib and libpq.5.dylib.

Also try to set my environment doing this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib
```

And in the python code:

```
import os
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib'
```

Still getting the same error.

If I look for:

```
locate libpq.5
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libpq.5.7.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpq.5.7.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpq.5.dylib
/sw/opt/postgresql-9.2/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
/sw/opt/postgresql-9.2/lib/libpq.5.dylib
/usr/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

and...

```
    locate libcrypto
/Applications/Adobe Stock Photos CS3/Adobe Stock Photos CS3.app/Contents/Libraries/libcrypto.dylib
/Applications/MEGA6.06-mac.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/Applications/MEGA6.06-mac.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libcrypto.a
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libcrypto.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libcrypto.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/sw/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
/usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
```

and...

```
locate libssl
/Applications/Adobe Stock Photos CS3/Adobe Stock Photos CS3.app/Contents/Libraries/libssl.dylib
/Applications/MEGA6.06-mac.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Applications/MEGA6.06-mac.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.dylib
/Applications/OpenOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/libssl3.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libssl.a
/Library/OpenSC/lib/libssl.dylib
/Library/OpenSC/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libssl.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/sw/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
```

EDIT: I already had Postgresql and psycopg2 imported and working, but Postgresql stopped listening to the server, and I ended up uninstalling and re-installing it again (after trying every single thing proposed in forums).

I am just starting working with python, SQL and even the bash! So this is just to much for me. I really appreciate if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Is your python version compiled with ssl support? try running `import ssl` to verify

Comment: Did you install psycopg2 before or after you installed Postgres?

Comment: @tutuDajuju Import ssl works!

Comment: @dirn I edited the text cause I forgot to mention that I had postgresql working with python before (we also had some issues importing psycopg2 but finally did it) but after some troubleshooting with postgresql (server not listening) I reinstalled it again.